# Remove .php in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website in a sub-folder on my webhost. And now I want to remove the .php from the url.

I have this .htaccess right now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder/

# remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And index works fine. But how do I fix this for other pages, like contact.php, about.php ect. Do I have to add this like all index.php in my .htaccess or how? Please help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do they not all bring you to the index with this redirectRulke?

Comment: Yes they bring me to index all the pages I've tried. If i try www.mysite.com/sub-folder/ I get index. If I try www.mysite.com/sub-folder/about I come to index to, for those pages I need to write .php in the end..

Answer (score 0):

Right below this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```